# why the order of actions matters when setting a floating ip on openstack horizon?

Tags: openstack, openstack-horizon

I would like to use openstack to setup instances of ubuntu/bionic. Prior automazing the vm instanciation with ansible/openstack API, I performed some tests through openstack horizon web interface. Basically I perform the following steps:

1. **create network: my-network**

   ```
   shared: False

   subnet:
       address: 192.168.66.0/24
       IP version: IPv4
       gateway: 192.168.66.254
       allocation pool: 192.168.66.100,192.168.66.200
   dns: my-dns-ips
   ```
2. **create router: my-router**

   ```
   external provider: provider
   interface:
        subnet: my-network
        ip: 192.168.66.254
   ```
3. **create instance: my-instance**

   ```
   network: my-network    
   security group: default + ssh + icmp
   keypair: generated via ssh-keygen and imported to horizon
   ```
4. **add floating ip to my-instance**

   ```
   ip: 192.168.13.209
   port to be associated: my-instance:192.168.66.123
   ```

when running those steps in the order: 1. 3. 2. 4., I can ping and ssh to my machine through its floating ip as expected. However, when running those steps in the order 1. 2. 3. 4., I can ping but I can't ssh with a `permission denied (publickey)` error.

Ideally, the order 1. 2. 3. 4. would have been the best for my future ansible needs as they would have allowed a clear (and clean) separation between the network setup and the instance allocation.

Could you tell me why this order triggers a ssh error while the other one works perfectly ?

Is that normal behavior and if so could you explain me why ?

[EDIT] digging further into the log of the successful and failing instances, I noticed that the failing one could not find the ssh key. This obviously explains the failing `ssh` but I still do not understand why in that case the keypair is not injected into the instance.

Answer (score 2):

That is because in your first try, the instance can get the metadata from the `DHCP-agent`. But in the second order, the network has a `gw` on the router and with that in the picture, `metadata-agent` comes in play. I can not specify the problem by this much information but I suggest to check `metadata_proxy_shared_secret` in neutron and nova config files. If that is not the case for you, could you post the config files of neutron services and explain which service is installed where?

Comment: thanks for the explanation. It really make sense. I could finally make it, without a clear understanding, by setting the the `os_server::config_drive` option to `True`.

Comment: you're welcome, I advise you to find the problem in neutron-metadata and l3 agents. while your solution works, it will not allow you to add user-data in cloud init. metadata-agent is the best way to inject metadata in instances.